# How to perform upsert operation from Azure Databricks on tables that are in Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql, pyspark, azure-sql-database, etl, azure-databricks

This is an ETL job. So, if today's data already exists in the target table (in Azure SQL Server), I need to replace the existing record with new record from today's processing. Otherwise, insert all the records. I believe this can be done by MERGE INTO command, but how do I perform upsert on Azure SQL database tables from Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid primary key violation issues when upserting data into a SQL Server table in Databricks, you can use the MERGE statement in SQL Server.

The MERGE statement allows you to perform both INSERT and UPDATE operations based on the existence of data in the target table. You can use the MERGE statement to compare the data in the source and target tables, and then insert or update the data as necessary.

Here's an example of how you could use the MERGE statement to upsert data into a SQL

To avoid primary key violation issues when upserting data into a SQL Server table in Databricks, you can use the MERGE statement in SQL Server.

The MERGE statement allows you to perform both INSERT and UPDATE operations based on the existence of data in the target table. You can use the MERGE statement to compare the data in the source and target tables, and then insert or update the data as necessary.

Here's an example of how you could use the MERGE statement to upsert data into a SQL Server table:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable AS target
USING (
  SELECT 
    Column1, Column2, Column3
  FROM 
    my_source_data
) AS source 
ON (target.PrimaryKeyColumn = source.PrimaryKeyColumn)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET
    Column1 = source.Column1,
    Column2 = source.Column2,
    Column3 = source.Column3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (PrimaryKeyColumn, Column1, Column2, Column3)
  VALUES (source.PrimaryKeyColumn, source.Column1, source.Column2, source.Column3);
```

In this example, dbo.MyTable is the target table in SQL Server, and my_source_data is the source data that you want to upsert into the target table. The PrimaryKeyColumn is the primary key column in the target table, and it is used to match records between the source and target tables.

The WHEN MATCHED clause is used to update existing records in the target table, and the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause is used to insert new records into the target table.

By using the MERGE statement, you can avoid primary key violation issues by checking for the existence of records before inserting new records into the target table. If a record with the same primary key already exists in the target table, it will be updated instead of inserted, which will prevent duplicates from being created.